# Moving a window from one activity to another activity- option missing now

Tags: window-manager

All was working good, till I got the recent update (which was yesterday). Now all of a sudden I don't see an option to move my window to another "activity".
Did anything change?

Normally I Rt click on the title bar of any window and chose move and then select the activity. Now it's gone.

My ubuntu is current, I use

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 
Release: 22.04 
Codename: jammy 
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.6 
KDE Frameworks Version:5.92.0 
Kernel Version: 5.15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised and also happy. It fixed by itself. Did Ubuntu roll out a patch?